# How can I add a fixed effect model label to an estout table?

Tags: stata

Below you can find my code:

```
#delimit;

local fixed_effect "Yes";

estout pre_post using output.xls, cells(b(star fmt(4) keep(post 
`ctrlVars')) t(par fmt(2) keep(post `ctrlVars'))) 
legend starlevels( * 0.10 ** 0.05 *** 0.010) stats(`fixed_effect' r2 N 
labels("Industry fixed effects" "Adjusted R-squared")) varlabels(_cons 
Constant) append;
```

This produces the following error message:

```
 ( invalid name
"Industry fixed effects invalid name
"Adjusted R-squared invalid name
 ) invalid name
r(7);
```

What is wrong?

---

**EDIT:**

Sorry for not being clear enough. This is what I would like to have:

```
----------------------------
                      (1)   
             Industry FEs   
                      b/t   
----------------------------
mpg             -174.3133*  
                  (-1.99)   
headroom        -520.2934   
                  (-1.23)   
length            31.3659   
                   (1.30)   
Constant        5540.3487   
                   (0.94)   
----------------------------
Industry FE        Yes
Adjusted R~d       0.2454   
N                 74   
----------------------------
* p<0.10, ** p<0.05, *** p<0.010
```

Comment: In the future please provide us with example data so we can easily replicate the problem. Read [How to create high quality reproducible examples in Stata](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377015/) for help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem using Stata's toy dataset `auto` as follows:

```
sysuse auto, clear

regress price mpg headroom length

#delimit;

esttab ., cells(b(star fmt(4)) t(par fmt(2))) 
legend starlevels( * 0.10 ** 0.05 *** 0.010) stats(r2 N
label("Industry fixed effects" "Adjusted R-squared")) varlabels(_cons 
Constant);

( invalid name
"Industry fixed effects invalid name
"Adjusted R-squared invalid name
) invalid name
r(7);
```

This error happens because you are using the options of the *community-contributed* command `estout` incorrectly: `labels()` is a sub-option of `stats()` and thus it has to be separated using a comma. In addition, you need the standalone option `mlabels()` to specify a custom model name:

```
esttab ., cells(b(star fmt(4)) t(par fmt(2))) legend ///
starlevels(* 0.10 ** 0.05 *** 0.010) stats(r2 N, labels("Adjusted R-squared")) ///
mlabels("Industry FEs") varlabels(_cons Constant)

----------------------------
                      (1)   
             Industry FEs   
                      b/t   
----------------------------
mpg             -174.3133*  
                  (-1.99)   
headroom        -520.2934   
                  (-1.23)   
length            31.3659   
                   (1.30)   
Constant        5540.3487   
                   (0.94)   
----------------------------
Adjusted R~d       0.2454   
N                 74.0000   
----------------------------
* p<0.10, ** p<0.05, *** p<0.010
```

Note that `delimit` also appears to cause some issues.

---

**EDIT:**

You need to use `estadd` for that:

```
sysuse auto, clear

regress price mpg headroom length

estadd local fe Yes

esttab ., cells(b(star fmt(4)) t(par fmt(2))) legend ///
starlevels(* 0.10 ** 0.05 *** 0.010) stats(fe r2 N, ///
labels("Industry FE" "Adjusted R-squared")) ///
mlabels("Industry FEs") varlabels(_cons Constant)


----------------------------
                      (1)   
             Industry FEs   
                      b/t   
----------------------------
mpg             -174.3133*  
                  (-1.99)   
headroom        -520.2934   
                  (-1.23)   
length            31.3659   
                   (1.30)   
Constant        5540.3487   
                   (0.94)   
----------------------------
Industry FE           Yes   
Adjusted R~d       0.2454   
N                 74.0000   
----------------------------
* p<0.10, ** p<0.05, *** p<0.010
```